# MediaElement Crash in CollectionView On IOS in MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

When placing a MediaElement inside a CollectioView, the app will crash when run on iOS, but not Android. See the error below:

```
ObjCRuntime.ObjCException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency Reason: child view controller:<AVPlayerViewController: 0x7f7a03092c00> should have parent view controller:<Microsoft_Maui_Controls_Handlers_Items_ReorderableItemsViewController_1: 0x7f79fcf64af0> but actual parent is:<Microsoft_Maui_Controls_Platform_Compatibility_ShellFlyoutRenderer: 0x7f79fcf35510>
Native stack trace:
0 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff8004288ab __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007ff80004dba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
2 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff800428789 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3 UIKitCore 0x000000011fc0295c -[UIView(Hierarchy) _associatedViewControllerForwardsAppearanceCallbacks:performHierarchyCheck:isRoot:] + 299
4 UIKitCore 0x000000011fc031ba -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 249
5 UIKitCore 0x000000011fc0408a _makeSubTreePerformSelector + 661
6 UIKitCore 0x000000011fc040d4 _makeSubTreePerformSelector + 735
7 UIKitCore 0x000000011fc040d4 _makeSubTreePerformSelector + 735
8 UIKitCore 0x000000011fc13b14 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 491
9 UIKitCore 0x000000011fb988ac -[UIScrollView _addContentSubview:atBack:] + 566
10 UIKitCore 0x000000011eadcefd -[UICollectionView _addControlledSubview:atZIndex:forced:initialAttributes:] + 970
11 UIKitCore 0x000000011eae1d9c -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 1637
12 UIKitCore 0x000000011eae1731 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 31
13 UIKitCore 0x000000011eaebd47 -[UICollectionView _createVisibleViewsForSingleCategoryAttributes:limitCreation:fadeForBoundsChange:] + 1731
14 UIKitCore 0x000000011eaec24b -[UICollectionView _createVisibleViewsForAttributes:fadeForBoundsChange:notifyLayoutForVisibleCellsPass:] + 376
15 UIKitCore 0x000000011eae9fad -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2331
16 UIKitCore 0x000000011eaf0bc4 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 375
17 UIKitCore 0x000000011fc1a59f -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2305
18 QuartzCore 0x00007ff80898b02c _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 526
19 QuartzCore 0x00007ff8089965b9 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 65
20 QuartzCore 0x00007ff8088a7b0c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 626
21 QuartzCore 0x00007ff8088df69b _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 735
22 UIKitCore 0x000000011f5e622b _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 70
23 UIKitCore 0x000000011f6b43be __processEventQueue + 9443
24 UIKitCore 0x000000011f6aa2a1 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 272
25 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff800387fe5 CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17
26 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff800387f24 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
27 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff800387721 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
28 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff800381e23 __CFRunLoopRun + 927
29 CoreFoundation 0x00007ff8003816a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
30 GraphicsServices 0x00007ff809cb128a GSEventRunModal + 139
31 UIKitCore 0x000000011f5e7ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
32 UIKitCore 0x000000011f5ec9ef UIApplicationMain + 123
33 libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib 0x000000010b76c64a xamarin_UIApplicationMain + 58
34 libmonosgen-2.0.dylib 0x000000010bf7a5a9 do_icall + 345
35 libmonosgen-2.0.dylib 0x000000010bf790b3 do_icall_wrapper + 291
36 libmonosgen-2.0.dylib 0x000000010bf6b4af interp_exec_method + 3295
37 libmonosgen-2.0.dylib 0x000000010bf68e03 interp_runtime_invoke + 259
38 libmonosgen-2.0.dylib 0x000000010bd8e0e8 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 136
39 libmonosgen-2.0.dylib 0x000000010bd960fc do_exec_main_checked + 92
40 libmonosgen-2.0.dylib 0x000000010bec4ce2 mono_jit_exec + 354
41 libxamarin-dotnet-debug.dylib 0x000000010b7b0c77 xamarin_main + 1927
42 CommunityToolkit.Maui.Sample 0x000000010aeff6f4 main + 52
43 dyld 0x000000010b44a2bf start_sim + 10
44 ??? 0x000000010cd0541f 0x0 + 4509946911
```

I have tried to add a media element in the collection view programmatically but got the same crash.
I want to see multiple videos at a time.

Comment: I reproduced your issue, and this issue can be tracked on this thread: [BUG  MediaElement Crash in CollectionView On IOS](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/1421).

Answer (score 0):

I just found a workaround for my case. If I add a dummy hidden MediaElement in the XAML above where I'm trying to bind, it processes as expected.

```
<toolkit:MediaElement IsVisible="false" />
```

Note: I'm also using a Bindable VerticalStackLayout instead of a CollectionView because of [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9135).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to achieve a "list of videos", but I am not convinced that attaching a `MediaElement` to a `CollectionView` or `ListView` is good for performance.

Instead, there I would set only one instance of `MediaElement` in the page, and only show "preview" images. Then, clicking on the image will load the video as a source of the unique `MediaElement`, and play.

I have written a series of articles about the `MediaElement`. If you are interested, you can start from [here](https://www.mauicestclair.fr/en/posts/tutos/my-first-app/10-play-music-with-mediaelement).